# Is any Martingale build from a Markov process?

Tags: probability, martingales, markov-process

A Markov process fulfills the relation:
$E[g(X_t)|F_s] = E[g(X_{t})|X_s]$
A function $h$ is harmonic iff $(h(X_t))_t$ is a Martingale.
Is any Martingale $(M_t)_t$ constructed from a Markov process $(X_t)_t$ and a harmonic function $h$ to this Markov process, such that $M_t=h(X_t)$?

That is: $\{h(X)|X$ is Markovprocess, $h$ is harmonic with respect to$ X\} \supset \{M|M$is a martingale$\}$

The question could also be stated as: Can one construct a fair game, that is not derived from a series of markovian random events.

Comment: Sorry but what is the question? Of course, for every Markov process X, there exists some functions h such that h(X) is a martingale...

Comment: Given a martingale M find a Markovprocess that one of its harmonic functions gives h(X)=M.

Comment: Well, without restrictions on the allowed constructions... Define $$X_t=(M_{t+s})_{s\geqslant0}$$ and $$h((x_s)_{s\geqslant0})=x_0$$ and you are done.

Comment: Very impressive, thank you very much.

Comment: What if $M_t \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X_t \in \mathbb{R}$ must hold?

Comment: Then we are back at my remark that "without restrictions on the allowed constructions..."

Comment: Yes that part of your answer got me curious.
I would suspect that the statement won't hold any longer.